# Who’s missing from this group of stars?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, letters

You’ve recently joined the Grey Elm, an exclusive VIP club, as an event organizer. Tonight’s event in particular features a lot of starpower, going by these aliases:

- Black-DRAGON
- GreenTurtleShells
- golden pigeon EIGHTEEN
- THRICE headed green birds

However, you need to invite one more act to round out the set. You’re racking your brain for the perfect choice…until you realize there’s one theme, one name that brings this whole list together. Yes, it has to be them. The final star group you invite is?…

—-

**Hint 1**:

> Each item in the list is a slightly modified reference to two somewhat niche, but globally recognized cultural media. One is hinted at through the literal description, another is hinted at through the non-standard words/letters.

**Hint 2**:

> The two cultural media are from Japan and Korea.

Comment: my (first) puzzle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group

> is the k-pop group **[SHINee](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinee)**

The reason

If you look at the names of the groups

> The words describe [SHINY POKÉMON](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon) from [Gen 1](https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/shiny). They are in order:
>
>  1) SHINY CHARIZARD
>
>  2) SHINY SQUIRTLE, WORTLE and BLASTOISE
>
>  3) SHINY PIDGEOT (18th MEMBER OF THE GEN 1 POKÉDEX)
>
>  4) SHINY DODRIO

> The capital letters hint at popular [K-POP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-pop) acts albeit with some form of letter manipulation:
>
>  1) [G-DRAGON](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-Dragon).
>
>  2) [BTS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTS)
>
>  3) [SEVENTEEN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeen_(South_Korean_band))
>
>  4) [TWICE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twice)

According to the puzzle, the final group has to be What these ‘groups’ all have in common and a

> K-pop group with that commonality as their name extrapolating from all the K-pop act references.

> So they all contain shiny pokemon hence they are all ‘Shiny’. The K-pop group with such a name is [SHINee](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinee). (Their name seems to also match the uppercase and lower case mixture found in the other Groups).

Some Easter eggs according to the OP:

> ‘Star’ is heavily mentioned in the puzzle because it applies to both the Shiny pokemon symbol and K-pop stars.

Comment: rot(TIJOff) is the correct answer! Well done :)

Comment: Also, one final reference: rot(Aol dvyk "zahy" pz olhcpsf tluapvulk, huk pa hssbklz av ivao aol zopuf wvrltvu zftivs, hz dlss hz ilpun h "R-Wvw zahy".)

Comment: rot(Aol nyvbw'z uhtl pz Zlcluallu!)

Comment: @op that was my initial thought but then shouldn’t the whole word be highlighted it seems to not fit the pattern well imo??

Comment: Haha you’re right - edited

Comment: This was fun! But just to add for further puzzles you may post 1) it is generally advised to wait at least 24 hours before dropping hints to give everyone from different time zones a chance to have a look and 2) without your hints this puzzle I think would have been near impossible for a lot of people since the content is niche it would have been better to make the hints somehow weaved into the puzzle via some flavor text to begin with with. 

Comment: Thanks, will keep in mind! Glad that you solved it